# Vue js - upload multiple files(image and mp3) in same component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

**My issue is that i have created 2 input files ad assigned then 2 different methods but when vue js executes only file method weather i upload file in weather first or second image.**

```
  <input type="file" @change="onImageChange" id="file-upload" class="d-none uploadm_icon">
    
    <input type="file" @change="onSongChange" id="file-uploads" class="d-none uploadm_icon">
    
        onImageChange(e) {
            console.log("image")
        },
        onSongChange(e) {
          console.log("song")
        },
```

Comment: There are so many duplicates on StackOverflow for this. Please search before asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your method to the instance - so in your constructor add the following:

`this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to bind `this` with your ordinary functions in class components or use arrow functions. like:

```
constructor() {
    // ...
   this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Or

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
    // ...
}
```